# Question about selling iphone app

Tags: iphone, app-store

If I have app which is already on App Store is it allowed to sell it on my website ?

Comment: And how are you gonna distribute it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create website for it, you can promote it there, you can put direct link to the AppStore on your page, etc. But there's no other way how to distribute it - just AppStore. Otherwise users will no be able to install it on their phones.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this website, it has some information about promoting your app on your website. http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/faq.html